# How to fix msbuild path detection from Enterprise to Community edition

Tags: habitat, gulp

I'm facing issue running gulp successfully for installing Habitat with VS2017 Community edition.

I've checked the Node version, msbuild version and all is fine. But when I run gulp it automatically detects msbuild path as:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\**Enterprise**\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\amd64\MSBuild.exe

where as the actual path is:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\**Community**\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\amd64\MSBuild.exe

Any help to fix the msbuild path detection by gulp would be really appreaciated.

Below is the error I'm facing:

```
C:\projects\Habitat>gulp
[11:57:14] O---o   _____ _ _                            _   _      _ _
[11:57:14]  O-o   /  ___(_) |                          | | | |    | (_)
[11:57:14]   O    \ `--. _| |_ ___  ___ ___  _ __ ___  | |_| | ___| |___  __
[11:57:14]  o-O    `--. \ | __/ _ \/ __/ _ \| '__/ _ \ |  _  |/ _ \ | \ \/ /
[11:57:14] o---O  /\__/ / | ||  __/ (_| (_) | | |  __/ | | | |  __/ | |>  <
[11:57:14] O---o  \____/|_|\__\___|\___\___/|_|  \___| \_| |_/\___|_|_/_/\_\
[11:57:14]  O-o
[11:57:14]   O    -------------------- helix.sitecore.net ------------------
[11:57:14]  o-O
[11:57:14] o---O  The Habitat source code, tools and processes are examples of 
Sitecore Helix.
[11:57:14] O---o  Habitat is not supported by Sitecore and should be used at your own risk.
[11:57:14]  O-o
[11:57:14]   O    ----------------------------------------------------------
[11:57:14]  o-O
[11:57:14] o---O
[11:57:14] Using gulpfile C:\projects\Habitat\gulpfile.js
[11:57:14] Starting 'default'...
[11:57:14] Starting '01-Copy-Sitecore-License'...
Copying Sitecore License file
[11:57:14] Finished '01-Copy-Sitecore-License' after 43 ms
[11:57:14] Starting '02-Nuget-Restore'...
[11:57:15] MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '4.0' from 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319'.
All packages listed in packages.config are already installed.
[11:57:15] Finished '02-Nuget-Restore' after 1.01 s
[11:57:15] Starting '03-Publish-All-Projects'...
[11:57:15] Starting 'Build-Solution'...
[11:57:15] { Error: spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\amd64\MSBuild.exe ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1020:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:197:32)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:376:16)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
  code: 'ENOENT',
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual 
Studio\\2017\\Enterprise\\MSBuild\\15.0\\Bin\\amd64\\MSBuild.exe',
  path: 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual 
Studio\\2017\\Enterprise\\MSBuild\\15.0\\Bin\\amd64\\MSBuild.exe',
  spawnargs:
   [ 'C:\\projects\\Habitat\\Habitat.sln',
     '/target:Clean;Build',
     '/verbosity:minimal',
     '/toolsversion:15.0',
     '/nologo',
     '/maxcpucount',
     '/nodeReuse:False',
     '/property:Configuration=Debug',
     '/property:Platform=Any CPU' ] }
[11:57:15] MSBuild failed!
[11:57:15] 'Build-Solution' errored after 26 ms
[11:57:15] Error: spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\amd64\MSBuild.exe ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1020:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:197:32)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:376:16)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
[11:57:15] 'default' errored after 1.11 s
[11:57:15] Error in plugin 'run-sequence(Build-Solution)'
Message:
    spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\amd64\MSBuild.exe ENOENT
Details:
    code: ENOENT
    errno: ENOENT
    syscall: spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\amd64\MSBuild.exe
    path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\amd64\MSBuild.exe
    spawnargs: C:\projects\Habitat\Habitat.sln,/target:Clean;Build,/verbosity:minimal,/toolsversion:15.0,/nologo,/maxcpucount,/nodeReuse:False,/property:Configuration=Debug,/property:Platform=Any CPU
Stack:
Error: spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\amd64\MSBuild.exe ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1020:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:197:32)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:376:16)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
[11:57:15] '03-Publish-All-Projects' errored after 48 ms
[11:57:15] Error in plugin 'run-sequence(default)'
Message:
    spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\amd64\MSBuild.exe ENOENT
Details:
    code: ENOENT
    errno: ENOENT
    syscall: spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\amd64\MSBuild.exe
    path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\amd64\MSBuild.exe
    spawnargs: C:\projects\Habitat\Habitat.sln,/target:Clean;Build,/verbosity:minimal,/toolsversion:15.0,/nologo,/maxcpucount,/nodeReuse:False,/property:Configuration=Debug,/property:Platform=Any CPU
Stack:
Error: spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\amd64\MSBuild.exe ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1020:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:197:32)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:376:16)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
[11:57:15] '03-Publish-All-Projects' errored after 55 ms
[11:57:15] Error in plugin 'run-sequence(Build-Solution)'
Message:
    spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\amd64\MSBuild.exe ENOENT
Details:
    code: ENOENT
    errno: ENOENT
    syscall: spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\amd64\MSBuild.exe
    path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\amd64\MSBuild.exe
    spawnargs: C:\projects\Habitat\Habitat.sln,/target:Clean;Build,/verbosity:minimal,/toolsversion:15.0,/nologo,/maxcpucount,/nodeReuse:False,/property:Configuration=Debug,/property:Platform=Any CPU
Stack:
Error: spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\amd64\MSBuild.exe ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1020:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:197:32)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:376:16)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
```

Below is my Packacge.json:

```
{
  "name": "habitat",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Sitecore Habitat Node Dependencies",
  "main": "gulpfile.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "async": "^1.5.2",
    "glob": "^7.0.3",
    "gulp": "^3.9.0",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^3.1.0",
    "gulp-debug": "^2.1.2",
    "gulp-exec": "^2.1.2",
    "gulp-foreach": "^0.1.0",
    "gulp-load-plugins": "^1.0.0",
    "gulp-msbuild": "^0.4.4",
    "gulp-newer": "^1.0.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-rimraf": "^0.2.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^2.0.4",
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.7",
    "gulp-watch": "^4.3.5",
    "merge-stream": "^1.0.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.3",
    "rimraf": "^2.4.3",
    "run-sequence": "^1.1.4",
    "vinyl": "^1.1.0",
    "xml2js": "^0.4.16",
    "xmlpoke": "^0.1.12",
    "yargs": "^6.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp-msbuild": "^0.4.8",
    "gulp-nuget-restore": "^0.4.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/Sitecore/Habitat.git"
  },
  "author": "Sitecore Corporation A/S",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/Sitecore/Habitat/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/Sitecore/Habitat#readme"
}
```

gulp-config.js:

```
module.exports = function () {
  var instanceRoot = "C:\\websites\\Habitat.dev.local";
  var config = {
    websiteRoot: instanceRoot + "\\Website",
    sitecoreLibraries: instanceRoot + "\\Website\\bin",
    licensePath: instanceRoot + "\\Data\\license.xml",
    solutionName: "Habitat",
    buildConfiguration: "Debug",
    buildToolsVersion: 15.0,
    buildMaxCpuCount: 0,
    buildVerbosity: "minimal",
    buildPlatform: "Any CPU",
    publishPlatform: "AnyCpu",
    runCleanBuilds: false
  };
  return config;
}
```

gulp task:

```
gulp.task("03-Publish-All-Projects", function (callback) {
  return runSequence(
    "Build-Solution",
    "Publish-Foundation-Projects",
    "Publish-Feature-Projects",
    "Publish-Project-Projects", callback);
});
gulp.task("Build-Solution", function () {
  var targets = ["Build"];
  if (config.runCleanBuilds) {
    targets = ["Clean", "Build"];
  }

  var solution = "./" + config.solutionName + ".sln";
  return gulp.src(solution)
      .pipe(msbuild({
          targets: targets,
          configuration: config.buildConfiguration,
          logCommand: false,
          verbosity: config.buildVerbosity,
          stdout: true,
          errorOnFail: true,
          maxcpucount: config.buildMaxCpuCount,
          nodeReuse: false,
          toolsVersion: config.buildToolsVersion,
          properties: {
            Platform: config.buildPlatform
          }
        }));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The current master branch of Habitat is using v0.4.4 of the [gulp-msbuild](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-msbuild) package. That version was still using an iterative process to figure out the location of msbuild. Priority is given to the following versions, in order:

1. BuildTools
2. Enterprise
3. Professional
4. Community

This is a pretty limited process, because it doesn't allow for non-standard installations. It looks for each of the above folder names within `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017`. When it finds a folder that exists, it's considered the official version for building. So presumably you do have that folder on your drive: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise`. Removing it, if not needed, would resolve your issue.

What I would recommend though is updating the gulp-msbuild package (from your solution root: `npm update gulp-msbuild --save`). Since that version, this package has been updated to use [vswhere](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/heaths/2017/04/21/vswhere-is-now-installed-with-visual-studio-2017/) in order to locate msbuild. You can see the change [in this commit on GitHub](https://github.com/hoffi/gulp-msbuild/pull/60/commits/4388552aad26a6e4de892e568834dea8f4fd1be2).